# Ngif conditional array and output to child component does not work

Tags: angular, angular5

A post call returns a list of error messages that I send to employee-list-component through a service. There, it puts ngIf="errorlist" on the component 'error-message'. It also sends [errorlist]="errorlist" on the same component.

The error list component will then display the errors. For some reason this does not work. In my console log in my employee-list-component I can see that I get the list of errors, and it has e.g 3 in length so it should work!

employee-list component

```
@Component({
selector: 'employee-list component',
template: `
<div class="form-group">
<input class="new-style" type="text" [(ngModel)]="listFilter" placeholder="Filter employees..">
    <p class="new style">         
Showing{{filteredEmployees.length}} of{{totalCount}} employees.
   </p>
<ng-container *ngIf="errorList?.length">
    <error-message [errorList]="errorList"></error-message>
</ng-container>
<p *ngIf="errorList.length > 0">hello</p>
</div>
 `
})

export class employeeListComponent implements OnInit {
errorList: ErrorMessage[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
       .........
    this.validationService.errorEmitter.subscribe(
        (errorData: ErrorMessage[]) => {
            this.displayErrors(errorData);
        });
}

    displayErrors(data: ErrorMessage[]) {
    if (data.length) {
        this.errorList = data;
        console.log('errorList ', this.errorList);
        console.log('errorList length ', this.errorList.length);
    }
}
}
```

error-message component

```
@Component({
selector: 'error-message',
template: `
<ng-container *ngIf="errorList">
 <ng-container *ngFor="let error of errorList">
    <div class="validation-summary error no-shadow">
        <ul>
            <li>{{ error.SourceReference }}, {{ error.ErrorMsg }}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
 </ng-container>
</ng-container>
`
})
export class ErrorMessageComponent {
@Input()
errorList: ErrorMessage[] = [];


ErrorMsg: string;
SourceReference: string;
Properties: string[];

ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log('errorComp ', this.errorList);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the error component, the validationservice and the html from the employeelistcomponent to the parent of employeelistcomponent (employeeComponent) and now it works.. Not entirely sure why though. Maybe employeelist and errormessage are siblings?..